# Saga timeouts with SQS transport

Tags: amazon-sqs, messaging, nservicebus

NServiceBus docs say:

> The Timeout Manager is enabled by default. However, it is automatically disabled for send-only endpoints and transports that support delayed delivery natively (i.e. Azure Service Bus).

[SQL supports delayed messaging, yet max delay is 15 minutes.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html)

Is NSB clever enough to figure out that requested timeout period exceeds max SQS interval and switch back to [Timeout Manager](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/timeout-manager)? Or is it possible to force NSB to use Timeout Manager and ignore transport capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NServiceBus SQS transport has a feature called unrestricted delayed deliveries that enables the deferral of timeouts for an unrestricted period without using the TimeoutManager, using instead only the transport capabilities and FIFO queue support. You can find more information on the feature in the documentation https://docs.particular.net/transports/sqs/delayed-delivery